# Can sound be faster than 300m/s?

Tags: special-relativity, waves, speed-of-light, acoustics, relative-motion

If you sit in a car and it's driving $300{m \over s}$ and you clap your hands for a very very short sound, will it's wave be $600{m \over s}$ fast, because it adds the speed of the car? 
Or will it be $300{m \over s}$ because it is just the point of origin that matters and from that point it travels away?

If the answer of the title question would be yes, that would also mean that light can also travel faster than speed of light, right? (I assume sound and lightwaves can be compared as both contains electeomagnetic waves)

Comment: No, the velocities are not additive. See [sonic boom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_boom)

Comment: Is your question about sound or about light? Sound waves are fundamentally different from EM waves/light. The similar mathematics doesn't mean they are physically similar. And pure sound is *not* electromagnetic.

Comment: Sound waves are like what most physicists/philosophers thought light was, before Einstein & Co.  Sound must move in a medium, similar to the "aether" that was once hypothesized for light.  But light is different, and does not require an "aether" to propagate.

Comment: This example explains why physicists considered the aether to be a stationary medium through which light propagated. It turned out this mechanical model didn't wor and the aether concept was replaced by the field.

Comment: @BillN, they are more similar in behaviour than you might think. For example, sound waves exhibit time dilation when the air moves around stationary objects.

Comment: Of course. The speed of sound is different in every materiel, and varies within any materiel with the temperature. It is in fact the speed that the particles within the materiel are moving as a result of their thermal energy. The speed of sound in water is 1500 - 1530 meters/sec. In Steel it is almost 6000 meters/sec

Comment: Based on the second sentence of your question, Yes, the speeds are additive, since the speed of sound is the speed of the actual molecules of the medium the sound is traveling in. If you move the entire medium in some direction relative to another separate frame of reference, then the speed of sound within the medium, relative to the other frame of reference (like the ground outside the car), is of course additive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speed of sound of 340 m/s is measured with respect to air. So here we can mention two cases:

1. If you are inside a car that is moving at 340 m/s in the highway and the *windows are closed* (so that the air inside the car is also moving at that speed), the sound of your clap will move at 680 mm/s with respect to the ground. This is because it moves at 340 m/s with respect to the air inside the car.
2. Imagine the same situation but with a car that has no roof nor windows. Then you, inside the car, will find that the air moves at 340 m/s backwards. If you clap in this situation the sound waves will move at 340 m/s in the air, but because this air moves at 340 m/s backwards you will see that the sound waves do not move at all.

The second case is exactly what happens in this picture:
[image]
When the supersonic aircraft is moving exactly at (or very near) the speed of sound (both with respect to the air), the waves travel at the same speed and they accumulate to form that peculiar cone.

In the case of light the case is different because light speed is 300000 km/s with respect to space itself. And you cannot move with respect to space, you move in space with respect to other things. Motion is relative. So the speed of light is the same for everyone independent of the speed of the observer (or the source).

Comment: Worth noting that the air will only move 680 m/s if you ignore relativistic effects.  Realistically, relative to the ground frame it will be moving a little slower than 680 m/s if you account for relativity.  This might help OP wrap his head around why this fails when you try to apply it to light speed.

Comment: @JMac Thanks for the note, apart from your interesting fact I realized (with the help of the answer below, above and your comment) that sound and light is very different.

Comment: The speed of light is *not* the same for everyone independent of their speed - it is the same *locally* for everyone (relative to their local clock). That's a subtle difference.

Comment: Wrong, on many counts. The sound waves in the car do move. postulating a car with no doors or windows is equivalent to just moving a sound generator (like a speaker) through the air at the same speed. Sounds waves generated will move backwards through the air mass at exactly 340 m/s, although since the speaker is moving forwards at 340m/s, the speed of these backwards sound waves will be 680 m/s relative to the speaker. Sound waves moving forwards will also move through the air mass at 340m/s, but as the speaker is also moving forward at the same speed the relative speed will be zero.

Comment: The speed of Light is different. It will be measured at exactly the same speed (186,000 miles/sec) no matter how fast or slow the emitter, or the observer is traveling, with respect to each other or to any frame of reference.

Comment: @CharlesBretana, the reason lightspeed is numerically identical in all frames is because the rate of the clock is affected by the movement! So that any absolute reduction in lightspeed, is offset by a reduction in the clock rate (thereby maintaining the same relationship between time and distance). That change is presumably because all known clocks employ electromagnetism on some level. That's different from arguing that lightspeed (by reference to a single clock) is invariant - theory and experiment shows that it clearly isn't.

Comment: @Steve, My apologies, but this is not correct.  The rate of the clock is affected by the motion? What motion are you referring to? There is no such thing as absolute motion. All "motion" is only perceived, relative to the frame of reference you measure it in, and is only a perceived attribute, not an absolute. And "all known clocks use Electromagnetism at some Level"? What about biological processes? or atomic clocks that rely on decay rates? They depend on the weak force, not on electromagnetism. Read a bit... As Wolfgang Pauli is quoted, this is "not even wrong".

Comment: Read up about the Michelson-Morley experiment. simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experimen‌​t it was done in 1887. That's how long ago we have known that the speed of light is invariant.

Comment: @CharlesBretana, I know about the MM experiment - which falsified classical wave mechanics (as well as aether theories of the time), for which relativity was the replacement. I'm not an expert on atomic clocks, but are you saying they don't rely on EM? From what I understand, *all* atomic clocks are based on microwave signals, so it's certainly credible to suggest that they will slow down under movement - and that's consistent with experiment. You say motion is relative, but consider what SR predicts - it predicts that moving clocks slow *absolutely* according to *relative* motion....(1/2)

Comment: ...Also, the preferred frame by which motion is measured is the cosmic background. Nothing in the real world exists without the background. It can be neglected from consideration whenever the reference frame is roughly stationary relative to the background. (2/2)

Comment: @CharlesBretana, btw I just thought I'd add, you do realise that in *sonar*, when both source and receiver move relative to the air, the local frequency remains the same (i.e. not subject to Doppler), but the round-trip transfer time increases by the Lorentz factor? It's an inherent property of all kinds of waves.

Comment: ...And another thing (sorry!), decay rates mediated predominantly by the weak force are experimentally verified to be variable with speed - muon decay being an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72285/discussion-between-charles-bretana-and-steve).

Answer (score -1):

To answer the second question: sound waves are not electromagnetic waves, they're pressure waves.